# Assigning javascript value to Controller variable in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I try to assign javascript variable contentArea to content.Contents in my controller. How can I do that?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            var contentArea = tinyMCE.get("modalTextarea").getContent();

        });

</script>
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string test)
    {

        DBEntities dbTest = new DBEntities();

        tbl_Contents content = new tbl_Contents();

        content.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now;
        content.Title = "test";

        content.Contents = "content1";

        content.ImagePath = "image0";

        dbTest.AddToICE_tbl_Contents(content);
        dbTest.SaveChanges();
        return View();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an AJAX request to the action's URL containing the data:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Index")", { test: contentArea });
```

Comment: It still Null in my database. Data type of test parameter is string and contentArea is ntext. content.Contents = test; is it possible?